# Where can I visit the most northerly Australian fauna in the world?

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, factoids

In Asahiyama Zoo in Hokkaido, Japan (43.768533,142.482717), I saw a pair of emus. Are they the northernmost Australian fauna in the world, or is there a place even further north that has distinctly Australian fauna?

[image: Pair of emus in Asahiyama Zoo. Fair amount of snow, but the emus don't seem to be affected by it. Quickmeme caption: No, seriously ... where the bloody hell are we?]

Criteria:

- Can be in the wild or in captivity
- Has to be reasonably distinct - kangaroos would count even though they also occur in Papua New Guinea, but albatrosses probably wouldn't.

Comment: There's a half-dozen red kangaroos sharing an enclosure with some deer at Batumi Zoo in Georgia, which is at 41.646637,41.627508.

Comment: Not wishing to spoil the fun we had looking for the northernmost Australian animals, but 43 degrees north is not very far north. London is 51, Edinburgh 55.

Comment: Are you looking for natural Australian fauna or also for artificial Australian fauna?

Comment: @RoflcoptrException What's artificial Australian fauna? Cane toads?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm a zoo or something similar

Comment: @RoflcoptrException that was mentioned in the first criterion bullet point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently the **[Kitee (Finland) Zoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitee_Zoo) (62°02′45″N)** [has emus](https://web.archive.org/web/20140315082754/http://www.kiteezoo.fi/english/animalspdf.html).

According to Wikipedia, [Ranua, Lapland has the northernmost zoo in the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranua_Wildlife_Park) (65°56′32″N). I checked [the website](https://web.archive.org/web/20140315081733/http://www.ranuazoo.com/English/Winter/Animals); it doesn't seem to have anything I recognize as Australian (it lists mainly northern birds, and a surprisingly large number of species of weasels).

I also checked the [Ähtäri Zoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%84ht%C3%A4ri_Zoo) (62°32′20″N); [nothing Australian is listed](http://ahtarizoo.fi/templates/ahtarizoo2013/images/kartta/Elinpuistokartta-2013-syksykausi-leirint-auki.png). There are a few other northern [zoos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zoos):

- Reykjavík has one but I couldn't find much information
- Frösön, Sweden

In terms of feral Australian fauna, several northern European cities have [feral parrots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feral_parrots). The most common feral parrots are South American and Eurasian, but there might be Australian species present as well. (Budgerigars are also common generally, but [apparently they don't survive cold winters](https://web.archive.org/web/20140315075411/http://www.wildaboutbritain.co.uk/forums/general-wildlife/107597-budgerigars-wild.html)). Example: [An Indian species showed up in Edinburgh.](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/scotland/4665754.stm)

Comment: There is a tiny population of escaped wallabies in the Netherlands.

Answer (score 7):

The most northerly Australian animals I've personally come across were at the Copenhagen zoo.

In addition to the not-so-unexpected Kangaroos they also have a few Tasmanian Devils, and at least one Kookaburra! According to my GPS, it's at about 55.672° N, 12.523° E.

Heading even further north, the Helsinki Zoo in Finland [has both Emu and Red-necked Wallabies](http://www.korkeasaari.fi/service.cntum?pageId=130957).  It's at **60.1749° N, 24.9840° E**.

Leningrad Zoo also have some Kangaroos, but it's slightly further south than Helsinki (59.9525° N, 30.3087° E)

Comment: OK, gotta give you that. Kudos for the Helsinki finds.

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://www.tallinn.world-guides.com/tallinn_attractions.html) says that Tallinn zoo has kangaroos.  Tallin is at 59 degrees 26 mins north. A review on [this page](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowUserReviews-g274958-d522526-r16055258-Tallinn_Zoo-Tallinn_Harju_County.html) backs it up. So does [this picture](http://www.flickr.com/photos/64828569@N08/6899785474/).

I found a [newspaper report](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1301&dat=19501130&id=3_tUAAAAIBAJ&sjid=DpMDAAAAIBAJ&pg=7431,5358543) of a ship taking a kangaroo back to Leningrad Zoo (59 degrees 57 mins N) after their only one was killed in the war, but that was in 1950 and I can find nothing to say they still have one.

Comment: They appear to be Red-necked Wallabies, not Kangaroos. Still Australian though!

Answer (score 3):

[Inchconnachan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inchconnachan), 56 degrees 5 mins north, in [Loch Lomond](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Loch_Lomond), has a population of wallabies roaming wild.

Comment: Most northerly *wild* Australian fauna would be a whole other question.